# Big-O of log versus square root

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, big-o, logarithm

Generally speaking, is the following always true?

log(n) = O(n<sup>a/(a+1)</sup>)? s.t. *a* is any constant positive integer, perhaps very large.

If not, what is the largest value of *a* for which this statement will hold true?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As functions go, log(*n*) always grows slower than *n*<sup>*any power*</sup> when *n* gets large. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663818/does-the-logarithm-function-grow-slower-than-any-polynomial for proof.

So as long as *a* is a constant positive integer, it really doesn't matter what its value is, as it will always be possible to find constants *C* and *k* such that log(*n*) <= |*C*(*n*<sup>*a*/(*a*+*1*)</sup>| + *k*, which is the definition of big-O.

However, you can also understand it intuitively: *n*<sup>*a*/(*a*+*1*)</sup> approaches *n* as *a* becomes large. Naturally, log(*n*) is always O(*n*).

Comment: *" it really doesn't matter what the value of a is"*: it does matter a bit though: will it hold when *a* is in the interval [-1, 0]?

Comment: You've misunderstood. He's asking about the complexity of the function log(N), when N gets arbitrarily large.

Comment: @trincot, the OP specifies that a is "any constant positive integer." a cannot be in the interval [-1, 0].

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean I don't understand the distinction between your comment and the question I answered.

Comment: @pymaxion, so it does matter then. Your statement could be understood to mean that the constraint that the OP put on the variable a is not relevant.

Answer (score 3):

The basic fact is that because of the concavity of the logarithm, it is always below its tangent. So

```
log(x) <= log(e) + 1/e * (x-e) = x/e
```

Thus

```
log(n) = O(n).
```

Now it is only necessary to apply logarithm laws to find

```
log(n) = 1/c * log(n^c) <= 1/(ce) * n^c
```

and thus `log(n)=O(n^c)` for any positive `C`.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `log(n)∈O(n^(a/(a+1))`, yes this is true for all positiv Integers for a, because `a/a+1 < 1 => n^(a/(a+1) ∈ O(n)` and because of `log(n) ∈ O(n) => log(n) ∈ O(n^(a/(a+1))`