# Given array with n numbers, it is known that 9 appears at-least n-n^(99/100) times in the array. Is there comparison-sort algorithm in O(n) time?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

**Problem:** We are given an array with `n` numbers and it is known that the number `9` appears at-least `n-n^(99/100)` times in the array.
*Prove/Disprove:* There exists a comparison-based algorithm that sorts the given array in linear time.

*Note:* comparison-sort based algorithm is discussed and not non-comparison-sort algorithms like counting sort, radix sort...

**Attempt:** I think the answer is a disproof but I don't really know how to justify my claim. I learned that the lower-bound at worst-case on comparison-sort algorithms is  `Ω(nlogn)` , thus a lower bound for sorting rest of the `n^(99/100)` elements in the above array at worst case will be `Ω( n^(99/100)log(n^(99/100))) = Ω( n^(99/100)log(n))` which is not linear, after sorting we place the `9` in the appropriate index, that'll cost `O(n^(99/100))` at worst-case ( we're going over all the elements in the up-to now sorted array in order to find the neccessary index ).
( I don't know what other important information I can deduce from the problem, so I'm stuck )

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: " `Ω( n^(99/100)log(n))` which is not linear " -- are you sure about that?

Comment: It appears @kcsquared is right. Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39982503/18781269

Comment: It seems that indeed `n^(99/100)log(n) = O(n)`, hence the answer to the above problem is indeed a proof and I could take for example merge-sort which sorts in `O(nlogn)` in worst case and then the given , specific array will be sorted in `O(n)` using some justifications provided in the comments and in my attempt.